# Orthogonal circles and chords

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, ratio

Two circles cut orthogonally in $A$ and $B$ . A diameter of one of the circles is drawn cutting the other circle in $C$ and $D$. Prove that $BC \cdot AD = AC\cdot BD$.

I have attempted a proof based on similar triangles and the usual angle theorems such as alternate segment,but can’t complete the proof.Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Don't you mind inserting a picture? Thanks.

Comment: Btw, a diameter of one of the cycles segment _can"t_ cut the other in two points, only one. A _line, containing diameter_ can.

Comment: Sorry for misleading you,it is,of course,better to say “a line containing a diameter”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Orthogonality means that $OB\bot BO'$ so $OB$ is tangent to circle with center at $O'$.

Because of tangent chord property we see that (blue) $$\Delta BCO\sim \Delta DBO\implies {OB\over OD} = {BC\over BD}$$
Similary (red) we have $$\Delta ACO\sim \Delta DAO\implies {OA\over OD} = {AC\over AD}$$

Since $OA = OB$ we are done.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your clear proof

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Solution from a friend of mine (with a large contest-math geometry background).
$\angle OAC=\angle ADC$ by [Tangent-secant theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent-secant_theorem), hence $$\triangle OAD\sim \triangle OCA\Rightarrow \frac{AC}{AD}=\frac{OC}{OD}.$$
Similarly $$\frac{BC}{BD}=\frac{OC}{OD}
\hbox{, hence }\frac{BC}{BD}=\frac{AC}{AD}\Rightarrow
BC\cdot AD=AC\cdot BD\hbox{, QED.}$$

Comment: Thank you (or rather your friend!) for the proof.

Comment: You're welcome)